# How to save update attribute on join table for has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models `Webinar`, `Participant` and join `Participant_webinar` the models are connected with `has_many through:`

```
class Webinar < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participant_webinars
  has_many :participants, through: :participant_webinars
```

```
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participant_webinars
  has_many :webinars, through: :participant_webinars
```

```
class ParticipantWebinar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :webinar
  belongs_to :participant

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participant
```

I need an extra column for connected that I've added as boolean in the `participant_webinar` table (some of the participants subscribe to webinar but don't participate).

I don't know how to edit or update the connected attribute

I've tried with nested attributes but it doesn't save or it duplicates the fields in the table:

```
<%= f.fields_for :participant_webinars do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.label :connected %>
  <%= ff.check_box :connected %>
<% end %>
```

I get this:

```
participant_webinars: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
           connected: '1'
           permitted: false
    converted_arrays: !ruby/object:Set
                hash:
                  *1: true
              commit: Update Participant
          controller: participants
              action: update
                  id: '1'
           permitted: false
```

Even if i have the params permited:

```
def participant_params
  params.require(:participant).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :qualification, :city, :file, webinar_ids: [], particpant_webinars: [:id, :webinar_id, :participant_id, :notconnected])
end
```

First I create the webinar then i have in the new participant a collection to select the webinars and I also want a checkbox for connected on each webinar that the participant is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

```
class Participant < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :participant_webinars
    has_many :webinars, through: :participant_webinars  
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :participant_webinars, 
    reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:connected].blank? }, allow_destroy: true 

    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
```

and in edit:

```
`<% if @participant.webinars.any? %>
<div class="form-group" >
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" > <hr><hr> 
          <%= f.fields_for :participant_webinars do |d| %>
          <%= d.hidden_field :participant_id, value: @participant.id %>
          <%= render 'participants/participantconnected', d: d %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <% end %>`
```

the partial:

```
`<li class="list-group-item"><% webinar = d.object.webinar %>
<%= webinar.name %>&nbsp; 
<span class="pull-right"><%= d.check_box :connected %> Connected?</span></li>`
```